# how do I attach the image the user uploaded from <form> (phpmailer)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, attachment

I have a simple form here

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Contact Number:<br>
<input type="text" name="contactnumber"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>

<input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" accept="image/png"/><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send">

<input id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

How do take the attached image and mail it via php mailer?

```
$uploadedfile = $_POST['filename'];
echo $uploadedfile;
```

if I try to echo them I only get the file name.

using PHPmailer

```
$mail->AddAttachment(../../../); // add attachments
```

I have this but I do not know how to put the image there.

I'm new to this so any help would be great!

After changing the `<form>` tag with the help of the comments I changed this too

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['filename']['name']);
```

now the error message is Could not access file: xxx.png 
any idea why?

Comment: `<form action="mail.php" method="POST">` isn't going to submit a file.. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php Specifically `Be sure your file upload form has attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work.`

Comment: It's not `$_POST` you're looking for but `$_FILES`. Try something and do a var_dump($_FILES) to see what it contains.

Comment: @chris85 has a point, you should add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your <form> tag...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: i have added   enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form tag and changed   $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['filename']); but it still doesnt work. the error message is Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer_5.2.4\class.phpmailer.php on line 1723 Could not access file @chris85

Comment: Why are you using such an old version? Is it really so hard to [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) and base your code on [the example provided that does exactly what you ask](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps)?

Comment: @Synchro thanks ive updated it anyway i found a working way with the link marc B gave thanks everyone

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_FILES['filename']) && $_FILES['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['filename']    ['name']); // add attachments
}
```

this solved all my problems i hope it helps yall too

Comment: Don't do this, it's not safe. Do what the PHPMailer examples tell you to do.